# confused in linear property?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, nonlinear-system

I have a system

> $$y(t)=3x(t)+2\cos(\pi t/3)$$

I am confused if this function/system is linear or not?
As if only we had $y=3x$, it would be definitely linear but now due to cos term, scenario complicates?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: A linear system has the property $y(ax+bz) = ay(x) + by(z)$, where $a,b$ are constants. Does cosine have this property? It doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linear system is one in which two things happen

1) Scaling the input by $a$, scales the output by $a$

2) The the output of the sum of two inputs to the system is the same as adding the outputs of each input individually

This is *not* the same as saying the graph is a line. For example, $y=ax+b$ (where $x$ is the input) is not a linear system (more specifically it is *affine*). Doubling the input does not double the output (i.e. $2y = 2ax + 2b \ne a(2x) + b$). In your system, doubling the input also does not double the output, so this is not a linear system

Answer (score 0):

It would be linear as a function of $x$, but not as a function of $t$. I.e.: if you assume $x$ is the variable and $t$ a constant $y(x)$ is linear, because is of the form $y(x)=ax+b$, where $a=3$ and $b=2\cos(\pi t/3)$. However, $y(t)$ with respect to $t$ doesn't satisfy this property.